# Display Data from MYSQL using PHP Dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I need to display data from the 'Members' table based on the selected 'grad_date' from a drop down. I have been trying to do it for a while now but have struggled to get it to work. Currently I have:

```
    <body>

  <!-- HTML code can reside ABOVE and BELOW the starting and closing PHP tags -->
    Select Grad Date
    <?php
        require_once 'login_name.php'; 
        $db_server = mysqli_connect(...)
        if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_error($db_server));

        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT grad_date FROM Members;";

        //As we have already connected to the database, execute the query stored in the $sql variable
        $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $sql);

        //Check if the query was successfully executed: if the result is NOT FALSE


        //More advanced logic can also be done based on success or failure
        if($result)
        {
            //Create Drop-Down Menu
            echo "<select name='Members'>";

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                //Store each SQL row's column name/value pair in a PHP variable
                foreach($row as $key=>$value) ${$key}=$value;

                //Load data onto drop-down menu
                echo "<option value='$grad_date'>$grad_date</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";

        }

            ?>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th> member_id </th>
                    <th> member_first_name </th>
                    <th> member_last_name </th>
                    <th> team_id </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
  <!-- HTML code can reside ABOVE and BELOW the starting and closing PHP tags -->
    </body>
```

I have tried a couple different things to go from here but have not found any success. How can I do this?

Comment: so what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I have the dropdown, but I cannot figure out how to make it display the table results. For example if I select 2025-10-05 as a grad date I want it to display all the results from 'Members' who have that as the grad date.

Comment: Ok. Sounds like you need to learn about HTML forms, and how to handle them using PHP, and then SQL `WHERE` clauses

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.